# ユーザーがアクセスするページ毎に違うパスワードを設定し、閲覧制限をかけたい。

Tags: security

不特定ユーザーがアクセスするサイト上に、
ページ毎に違うパスワードを発行し、パスワードを知ってるユーザーのみアクセスさせたいと思っています。

basic認証やhttaccessではなく、サーバサイド側での処理にしたく、パスワードはmysql上からひっぱってくることを想定しています。

イメージ的には、wordpressの記事別パスワードのような形なのですが、
このようにページ毎にパスワード認証をかける、というのは一般的にどのような理論で作られるのでしょうか。
パスワード認証時のセッション情報にページ毎に一意の値を入れて、逐次それを確認する、というような形なのでしょうか。
どなたかご教示頂きたく、何卒よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2):

不特定ユーザーがアクセスするというのは、会員制のサイトではないということですよね。
書いていらっしゃるとおり、セッションにその記事のパスワード認証に成功したという情報を持たせるだけで十分ではないでしょうか。